# How to inlude multiple barcodes inside of the svg file

Tags: svg, jsbarcode

I want to create a svg file with some bar codes inside.
So I have tried

```
<svg width="400" height="202" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
 </g>

<svg id="barcode1"></svg>
<svg id="barcode2"></svg>
<svg id="barcode3"></svg>
 
<script xlink:href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/barcodes/JsBarcode.code128.min.js"></script>
<script>
JsBarcode("#barcode1", "Hi!");
</script>
</svg>
```

So I get " Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement(...).getContext is not a function"
It doesn't seem to work inside of the svg file, so how can I achieve that?

Comment: try using [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead

Comment: What do you mean? You want me to modify condensed JsBarcode file???

Comment: jsBarcode expects to be in an HTML document. Not an XML document (like an SVG).  The code of jsBarcode would need to be modified.  You may want to make a feature request to the author.